# Nexus 3172T MTU

Tags: cisco, switch, layer2, mtu, cisco-nexus

I am attempting to set the L3 mtu on a Nexus port.
The mtu option is only available if I set "no switchport" which then prevents me configuring VLAN related settings.
Am I missing something obvious? Why can't I set the interface MTU and also configure VLANs?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the Nexus 3172 can only do QoS MTU, not per port MTU.

[*Configure and Verify Maximum Transmission Unit on Cisco Nexus Platforms*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/118994-config-nexus-00.html)

> ### Layer 2 MTU Configurations
>
> Layer 2 MTU is set either through a network Quality of Service (QoS)
>   policy or by configuring the port itself (on switches that support
>   per-port MTU). Only the Nexus 7K, 9K, and certain 3K models support
>   per-port MTU.
>
> **Network QoS MTU Configuration**
>
> **Nexus 3K:** Includes Nexus 3048, 3064, 3132Q, 3132Q-X, 3132Q-XL, 3172, and 3500-series switches
>
> **Nexus 5K:** All Nexus 5000 and 5500-series switches
>
> **Nexus 6K:** All Nexus 6000-series switches
>
> In order to configure elevated MTU on these switches, create a
>   **network-qos** policy or modify an existing policy in order to specify the elevated MTU. This configuration applies to all ports.
>   This includes any Cisco Fabric Extender (FEX) ports connected to the
>   switch. Per-port MTU is not supported.
>
> ```
> policy-map type network-qos jumbo
>   class type network-qos class-default
>           mtu 9216
> system qos
>   service-policy type network-qos jumbo
> ```
>
> **Per-Port MTU Configuration**
>
> **Nexus 3K:** Includes Nexus 3132Q-V, 3164, 31108, 31128PQ, 3200-series, and 36180YC-R switches
>
> **Neuxs 7K:** All Nexus 7000- and 7700-series switches
>
> **Nexus 9K:** All Neuxs 9200-series switches (including 92xxx), 9300-series switches (including 93xxx), and 9500-series switches
>
> In order to configure MTU on a per-port basis, the following
>   configuration is needed:
>
> ```
> Nexus(config)#interface ethernet 1/1
> Nexus(config-if)#mtu 9216
> ```

Comment: It may be worth noting that Nexus 3164Q and 31128PQ are actually tuned-down 9300 Series Variants, in general, as well as in this context of configuring MTU.

Answer (score 4):

Usually Nexus have this config section:

```
policy-map type network-qos jumbo
  class type network-qos class-default
    mtu 9216

 ...
system qos
  service-policy type network-qos jumbo
```

While this works and enables a Nexus for jumbo frames at L2, I personally consider it a bad example of config item naming, as the term "jumbo" is misleading as to what it is or what it does: It's actually the name of a policy-map.

Note: the given (layer 2) port of the Nexus configured this way will still show 1500bytes MTU in show commands and in CDP/LLDP information. All the same, it will process packets up to 9216 in both ingress and egress directions.

Because there might be other system-wide settings which must be defined by `system qos`, and because `system qos` can only take one single service-policy/policy-map, it is not very clever to call that single policy-map "jumbo".

Whenever I have the liberty to do so, I rewrite this as:

```
policy-map type network-qos PMAP-NQOS-SYSTEM
 !class type CMAP-NQOS-NNNNnnn       <--- room for other classes/class-maps used by 'system qos'
 !   <action/setting>                <--- actions/settings for other system wide classes
 class type network-qos class-default
     mtu 9216

! ...
! 'system qos' can take only one and exactly one service-policy
! ...
system qos
     service-policy type network-qos PMAP-NQOS-SYSTEM
```